# How to make an <i> tag an HREF on Bootstrap3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons, search-box

I'm working with Bootstrap version 3.3.4 and I'm trying to make a search form, however, in order to make my search glyphicon get inside my search bar I need to use an  tag , here is the code I'm currently using:

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="/search/" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div>
          <div class="right-inner-addon>
             <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('searchform').submit();" ><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a>
              <input id="query" name="query" type="search" class="form-control searchbox" placeholder="Search" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

As for Css I only use this costum apart, aside from all the bootstrap:

```
.searchbox {
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Even though when clicking enter the search bar works, for some reason the  glyphicon-search won't work as button so users also have the option on clicking on it to complete their search.
Any ideas ? :S

Comment: Assuming you can't use `<image type="image" src="yourglyph.png" alt="submit" />` here?

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle with this issue.

Comment: use the `span` inside a button. `<button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>`

Comment: Where is this `.searchbox` element? What do you mean by won't work as a button? Do you see the glyph? Does clicking on it not work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing a closing `"` after `<div class="right-inner-addon>`, which is causing the rest of your code to render improperly. Fix your code like this:

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="/search/" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
  <div>
    <div class="right-inner-addon">
      <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('searchform').submit();" ><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a>
      <input id="query" name="query" type="search" class="form-control searchbox" placeholder="Search" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And it works fine.

Check this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/vLg0ZItjhD).

Always try to use an IDE (Netbeans, Visual Studio, etc) with syntax highlighting; this issue would have been caught instantly.

**Edit**

Since using the icon in the search-bar negates the ability to click on it, I would suggest using a segmented button (as I can't figure out a way to capture the click event on the icon and not the input). Here would be the code:

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="/search/" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
  <div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And another [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/tBmgLpd9BF).

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner.

Comment: From what I can tell it's not supposed to work as a submit button. You have to press Enter to submit the form.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do - the glyphicon is already inside and I wanna make it submit as well, even with the <a> tag wont display the href hand but if I remove the <i> tag the glyphicon-search won't stay inside

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing that. I don't think it will, as it's not treated as an `<a>` tag when used like that. When you click it, the focus goes to the input, and I'm not seeing a way to capture the click event.

Comment: Maybe a segmented input? Are you against changing the look/style of the search bar?

Comment: I'm open to suggestions

Comment: I made a quick edit. Although I just noticed I forgot the `name` attribute on the `<input>`.. Woops.

Comment: So its working, you can review it at the same link , however theres a wired shadow on mobile I can't seem to get rid off, let me know if you have any suggestion, thanks Tim!

Comment: No problem, glad you got that working. Checked it on my phone and on Firefox at small width, can't say I see that shadow you're referring to...

Answer (score 1):

My standard guess is based off of an assumption since I don't have a working version of your code.

Anchor tags typically do not have a specific height or width set to them on their own. It's very possible that your anchor tag does not have width or height while your icon does.

Open your browser's dev tools by right clicking the icon and selecting inspect element. You should be able to trouble shoot it from there.

Answer (score 0):

My guess.  If that's not working would be z-indexing.  I don't have firebug on my phone, but anyways if you hover over it does it only highlight the search bar? Or can you highlight the icon?  If you can't...in your CSS change the Z-index of the form to let's say

```
#YourFormID{
    Z-index: 1;
}
```

Then for the icon do

```
#yourIconID{
    Z-index: 100;
}
```

This will bring the icon on top of the form much like layers in a photoshop document.  If that doesn't work still, I'll try again tonight from my PC.  But if what everyone else says doesn't work...this may be your issue.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of Z-index initially, but that doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: Well then yea, if no-ones figured it out by tonight I'll go through it on my computer and try to figure it out for ya.

Comment: Hi, yes I've tried this and it didn't work , I went with Tim's answer but on mobile it looks wired :/